# Read / open MySQL database saved as .bak in Python

Tags: python, mysql

Is there a good way to read / open MySQL database saved as .bak file in Python?

Goal is to understand the MySQL database structure (what tables exists, how are they linked etc.).

Any suggestions are very much appreciated!

Many thanks.

Best regards,
Bjoern

Comment: https://www.rebasedata.com/python-read-bak maybe?

Comment: Would need a solution that works locally and not somewhere else...many thanks though!